# How can I sign a Safari Extension for just one computer?

Tags: sign, safari-extension

I wrote a Safari Extension that I'd like to have permanently enabled on my computer. It works fine, but I have to click `Develop -> Allow Unsigned Extensions` and enable it manually every time I open Safari for it to be available. I'm not really sure how the signing process works. Is there a way I can sign my extension for only this computer, without having to subscribe to an Apple Developer account?

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out. First thing to do was to create a development account with Apple (the free version). Then click on the `[Project Name] -> Build Settings` and ensure "Development Team" has your account selected (you'll have to add your account in `Xcode -> Settings -> Accounts` if you haven't done so already).
[image: Select development team]

Next, ensure `Automatically manage signing` is enabled for all "TARGETS" listed:
[image]

Then, go to `Product -> Archive` and wait until the project compiles. It will bring up a window similar to this one:
[image: Archive management]

Next, hit `Distribute App -> Custom -> Copy App` and choose where to export the app. After running the app, the extension will be available in Safari, even after restarting the browser.

That's it! Be aware that if you delete your app, it will also delete your extensions. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Does this last permanently or does the certificate run out after 7 days, like self-signed iOS Apps?

Comment: Haven’t changed anything since I posted and the extension still shows up checked in my Safari :)

Comment: I get certificate errors, like: No signing certificate "Mac Development" found